# Why is my dog separating one pup and moving him?

Tags: dogs, behavior, safety, breeding

My Shih Tzu is almost 2 years old and had her 1st litter 4 days ago. She keeps moving one pup, yet still nurses him. No physical problem or cleft mouth. I’m scared she’ll eat him, I’ve heard horrible stories about that.

Comment: How many puppies does she have in total? Animal mothers have very keen instincts and can detect things like birth defects (and we have no idea how they do that). This could be a sign that the puppy is not healthy.

Answer (score 2):

Going along with what Elmy [said](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/29921/why-is-my-dog-separating-one-pup-and-moving-him#comment41383_29921) in the comments:

Mothers can detect birth defects as they can detect cancer in humans, You should get it checked out. It could be that the mother is protecting the one pup from the other pups for some reason although I have no idea why. If I could guess, it's because the pup doesn't need to drink that much so the mother would let the pup have the rest of the milk. I would still get the puppy checked out by a veternarian just in case.

Comment: +1 good answer. I think it would be even better if you could add a few sources (not that I think your info is untrue, just that it would just be a more scientific answer).